# What are y_weights, y_loadings and y_rotations in sklearn PLS

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, latent-variable, partial-least-squares

The partial least squares is an algorithm that seeks to decompose two data matrices $X$ and $Y$ based on a latent structure of the form:

$$X=TP+E$$
$$Y=UQ+F$$

where $T$ and $U$ are score matrices, and $P$ and $Q$ are loadings matrices. Now, using the sklearn implementation it is easy to see that the equation described for the $X$ matrix is true, but the equation for $Y$ is not. My question is:

1. What are then these `y_` matrices used for?
2. Am I doing something wrong on the calculations below?

See a fully reproducible example below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

# Load a dataset
boston = load_boston()
x = boston.data
x = x[:, [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]]  # select non-categorical variables
y = boston.target

n_comp = x.shape[1]

# PLS in python
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=n_comp, scale=False)
pls.fit(x, y)

t_pls = pls.x_scores_
w_pls = pls.x_weights_
p_pls = pls.x_loadings_
r_pls = pls.x_rotations_

u_pls = pls.y_scores_
c_pls = pls.y_weights_
q_pls = pls.y_loadings_
d_pls = pls.y_rotations_
```

Now see how the properties for the $X$ matrices hold:

```
x_center = x - np.mean(x, axis=0)
y_center = y - np.mean(y, axis=0)

# X = T P.T
x2 = t_pls @ p_pls.T
print(f'The difference between the two matrices is: {np.round(np.sum(np.abs(x_center - x2)), 5)}')
The difference between the two matrices is: 0

# T = XR
t2_pls = x_center @ r_pls
np.sum(t_pls - t2_pls)
print(f'The difference between the two matrices is: {np.round(np.sum(np.abs(t_pls - t2_pls)), 5)}')
The difference between the two matrices is: 0
```

But the properties for the $Y$ matrixdo not:

```
# Y = U Q.T
y2 = u_pls @ q_pls.T
print(f'The difference between the two matrices is: {np.round(np.sum(np.abs(y_center - y2)), 5)}')
The difference between the two matrices is: 15776.911

# U = YD
u2_pls = y_center @ d_pls
np.sum(u_pls - u2_pls)
print(f'The difference between the two matrices is: {np.round(np.sum(np.abs(u_pls - u2_pls)), 5)}')
The difference between the two matrices is: 131418.08854
```